# How to initialize primefaces scrollPanel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When "text" variable is too long and doesn't fit the screen,At first dialog load ScrollPanel is not rendering. After I resize the dialog, It appears. Is there any solution?

```
<p:dialog id="logDetailsDialogId" header="Log Details" appendToBody="true"                
                  widgetVar="logDialog" resizable="true">  
    <p:scrollPanel>
        <h:outputText value="#{myController.text}"/>
    </p:scrollPanel>
</p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding width and height to your `p:dialog` fixes the issue.

```
<p:dialog id="logDetailsDialogId" header="Log Details" appendToBody="true"                
              widgetVar="logDialog" resizable="true" width="800" height="600">  
    <p:scrollPanel style="height">
        <h:outputText value="#{myController.text}"/>
    </p:scrollPanel>
</p:dialog>
```

Note : Values can be set in %, but rember it will take % from parent, by default the body has no height so it will take 100%.

Answer (score 1):

With dynamic dialog content, this is not possible. What works is

```
<p:scrollpanel mode="native" />
```